# Is there a way to utilize all cpu cores and power in calculations?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

First, I've tried to use multithreading solution for this problem and discovered that it is not suitable for this purpose. Then I tried as community suggested to apply multiprocessing solution to bypass the GIL and even that performs poor compared to single process single thread code. Is python flawed in this domain?
Is the only solution for heavy cpu calculations is to drop python for another language?
I post my multiprocessing test code so you can get an impression.

```
from itertools import cycle
import random
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
```

```
# The class that represents the process
class Task(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}, *, daemon=None):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, group=group, target=target, name=name, args=args ,kwargs=kwargs, daemon=daemon)
        self.inputs = []

    def run(self):
        print(f"{self.name} is running")
        for arr in self.inputs:
            arr.sort()
    
    def add_input(self, arr):
        self.inputs.append(arr)


# A util function to cycle on iterable a finite number of times.
def finite_cycle(cycle_on, times):
    infinite_cycle = cycle(cycle_on)
    for _ in range(times):
        yield next(infinite_cycle)


# Constants
THOUSAND = 1000
MILION = THOUSAND ** 2
PCNT = 2
TASK_CNT = 50 * THOUSAND

# Main
def main():
    processes = [Task(name = f"p{pid}") for pid in range(PCNT)]
    for pid in finite_cycle(range(PCNT), TASK_CNT):
        processes[pid].add_input([random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(100)])
    stime = time.time()
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    print(f"execution time: {round(time.time() - stime, 2)}")
    print("finish.")
```

And this is the single process single thread code which is faster for every varation of the constants.

```
def main():
    inputs = [[random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(TASK_CNT)]
    stime = time.time()
    for arr in inputs:
        arr.sort()
    print(f"execution time: {round(time.time() - stime, 2)}")
    print("finish.")
```

Comment: use `multiprocessing` instead of threading. It will spawn several process instead of several threads and you will be free from GIL. Python won't support real multithreading for decades (because of backward compatibility)

Comment: Yes but I have. Look at my code.

Comment: "Is Python flawed in this domain?" Python is flawed in a lot of things...

Comment: The time spent in the execution of your Task class's run() function appears to be very brief and almost certainly much shorter than the overheads involved in instantiating an asynchronous process. If your process involved (for example) disk I/O, you would probably begin to see the benefits of multiprocessing. Can you say more about why multithreading is inappropriate for your use-case?

Comment: You can run the code and see that it is not brief. Notice that I mentioned that I've tried my code in multiple variations of the constants. In this specific example you can see I use two processes. Each is assigned with 25,000 arrays to sort. You can play with the constants yourself and see.

Comment: It takes half a second to sort the arrays on my (already under load) laptop. That's really brief. On that sort of timescale the non-multithreaded approach will always be faster because the overhead of setting everything up dominates the run time. Bear in mind that on Windows it's spinning up an entire new Python interpreter for each child process.

Comment: Modifying the code so that it generates the arrays on demand as it sorts them, so it has a bit more work to do without obliterating the machine's memory by generating millions of arrays up front, I can push the run times up towards the minute mark and that shows a much more noticeable difference, exactly as you'd expect. 50,000 arrays of 1,000 values each takes 26 seconds in the multiprocessing case and 50 seconds in the single-threaded case.

Comment: Thank you Sir! I'll check it now for myself and hope to see the expected performance.

Comment: You are initializing rather large lists in the process's `__init__` method and they therefore exist in the main process's address space. When you execute `start` on the `Process` instance, before `run` can be invoked the entire object must be serialized/de-serialized to the actual physical process's address space. I imagine that represents a *not insignificant* amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my desktop the `run` methods averaged each approximately .125 seconds to run while the time elapsed between calling the first `start` method and the start of the first `run` method was approximately .23 seconds (i.e. 1628456465.1061594 - 1628456464.8741603), most of that time I believe taken by the serialization/de-serialization of `self.inputs`. See below, which is the original program with a few timings added.

The point is that multiprocessing has two sources of overhead that the non-multiprocessing program does not have:

1. Overhead in creating the processes.
2. Overhead in passing arguments to and getting results back from the process. This involves moving data from one address space to another (via various mechanisms) in many cases unless shared memory is being used.

Multiprocessing therefore only becomes advantageous when the processing itself (the `run` method in this case) is so CPU-intensive that the aforementioned costs of multiprocessing are offset by being able to "divide and conquer" the problem.

```py
from itertools import cycle
import random
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

# The class that represents the process
class Task(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}, *, daemon=None):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, group=group, target=target, name=name, args=args ,kwargs=kwargs, daemon=daemon)
        self.inputs = []

    def run(self):
        t = time.time()
        print(f"{self.name} is running at:", t)
        for arr in self.inputs:
            arr.sort()
        print('elapsed time =', time.time() - t)

    def add_input(self, arr):
        self.inputs.append(arr)


# A util function to cycle on iterable a finite number of times.
def finite_cycle(cycle_on, times):
    infinite_cycle = cycle(cycle_on)
    for _ in range(times):
        yield next(infinite_cycle)


# Constants
THOUSAND = 1000
MILION = THOUSAND ** 2
PCNT = 2
TASK_CNT = 50 * THOUSAND

# Main
def main():
    processes = [Task(name = f"p{pid}") for pid in range(PCNT)]
    for pid in finite_cycle(range(PCNT), TASK_CNT):
        processes[pid].add_input([random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(100)])
    stime = time.time()
    print('stime =', stime)
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    print(f"execution time: {round(time.time() - stime, 2)}")
    print("finish.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
stime = 1628456464.8741603
p0 is running at: 1628456465.1061594
elapsed time = 0.1320023536682129
p1 is running at: 1628456465.3201597
elapsed time = 0.11999750137329102
execution time: 0.62
finish.
```